# Populating a ListView using an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

My `Android` app needs to populate the `ListView` using the data from an `ArrayList`.

I have trouble doing this. Can someone please help me with the code?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You need to do it through an `ArrayAdapter` which will adapt your ArrayList (or any other collection) to your items in your layout (ListView, Spinner etc.).

This is what the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) says:

> A `ListAdapter` that manages a `ListView` backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single `TextView`. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a `TextView` in the larger layout resource.
>
> However the `TextView` is referenced, it will be filled with the `toString()` of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the `toString()` method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.
>
> To use something other than `TextViews` for the array display, for instance `ImageViews`, or to have some of data besides `toString()` results fill the views, override `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` to return the type of view you want.

So your code should look like:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

         // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, 
         // you already have yours).
         List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
         your_array_list.add("foo");
         your_array_list.add("bar");

         // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
         // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
         // array as a third parameter.
         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 your_array_list );

         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Amokrane Chentir: i could'nt get u ..... can u pls type the full program .... thanks

Comment: @KanNaN: Sure, can you see if my edit is more explicit to you?

Comment: @ Amokrane Chentir: I think that the "setContentView" method must be called before "findViewById" or else no ListView will be found.

Comment: List<String> is not recognized. why? i'm using android studio.

Answer (score 14):

[tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Also look up [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) interface:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Answer (score 11):

Try the below answer to populate listview using ArrayList

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<String> movies;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.list);

       // Get the reference of movies
       ListView moviesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

       movies = new ArrayList<String>();
       getMovies();

       // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
       ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
                 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movies);
       // Set The Adapter
       moviesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

       // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
       moviesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
       {
           // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
           {
               String selectedmovie=movies.get(position);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Movie Selected : "+selectedmovie,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        });
    }

    void getmovies()
    {
        movies.add("X-Men");
        movies.add("IRONMAN");
        movies.add("SPIDY");
        movies.add("NARNIA");
        movies.add("LIONKING");
        movies.add("AVENGERS");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Example extends Activity
{
    private ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> arrlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    //let me assume that you are putting the values in this arraylist
    //Now convert your arraylist to array

    //You will get an exmaple here

    //http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-into-an-array.html 

    private String arr[]=convert(arrlist);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bun)
    {
        super.onCreate(bun);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could implement a list view:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //We have our list view
    final ListView dynamic = findViewById(R.id.dynamic);

    //Create an array of elements
    final ArrayList<String> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    classes.add("Data Structures");
    classes.add("Assembly Language");
    classes.add("Calculus 3");
    classes.add("Switching Systems");
    classes.add("Analysis Tools");

    //Create adapter for ArrayList
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes);

    //Insert Adapter into List
    dynamic.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set click functionality for each list item
    dynamic.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("User clicked ", classes.get(position));
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, it'll just autofill the onItemClick() method. Now all you have to do is just add functionality to it. For my case, I just logged each element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

First I created the objects

```
ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
ArrayList<Albums> listAlbums;
```

Then on On Create method:

```
listview = findViewById(R.id.listviewAlbum);
listAlbums = new ArrayList<Albums>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
listAlbums);
listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And then if u are using an API u can use this code to get trough the dataset:

```
for (Albums albumaux : response.body()) {
       listAlbums.add(albumaux);
            }
       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```