# How to populate listview in android from ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating a ListView using ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist)

I'm trying to create a listview in android and i have a ArrayList that contain all list data but i'm facing problem showing data in listview. Anyone explain me how it can be possible. Please refer some example too. Thanks.

Comment: [See this Example...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: check this: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For suppose listitems is the arraylist then you need to append your arraylist to listview as

```
//Declaration part
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
lv  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

//arraylist Append
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(From.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listItems);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```