# How to convert ArrayList to ListView?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm programming an Android application and one feauture is a `ListView` generated and populated by a MySQL Database.

This is the outputted ArrayList:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); 
List<Suspect> list = db.getAllContacts();
```

Do I use a `cursor` to input it in my `ListView`?
Any code would be appreciated..

Comment: You can use an ArrayAdapter. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5070922/2198638

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [CursorAdapter](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) in case you don't need any data manipulations after the query. 
If you want to use List so try [ArrayAdapter](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify the data after it is captured from the database and have the view updated I'd suggest you create an arrayList of , and then you can use a custom Array Adapter like shown [here](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/). If you then change the underlying data, you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()