# Add the values on ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have develop one application. Here i have to add the value on `ArrayList`. if i have to click `Button` means that value have to add on that `ArrayList`. I have to click another `Button` means that added list is displaying. How can i do? Please give me solution.

**These are my values:**

```
 product_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
         product_title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
         product_image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
         product_price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");
         product_desc = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add(product_title);
    arrayList.add(product_price);
    arrayList.add(product_id);
    arrayList.add(product_image);
    arrayList.add(product_desc);
```

I have to add these values on `ArrayList` while clicking the `Button`:

```
  valueaddlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valueaddlist);
        valueaddlist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddedListProducts.class);
    intent.putExtra("WishListProducts", arrayList);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

In the `AddedListProducts` have to displaying all added products list.

How can i do ?
please give me solution for these ?

**EDIT:**

This is my AddedListProducts class code:

```
wishlist_products = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wishlist_products);
    if(getIntent().getExtras() !=null){
        WishListProducts = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("WishListProducts");
        System.out.println(WishListProducts);
        wishlistproductsAdapter = new WishListAdapter(this,WishListProducts);
        wishlist_products.setAdapter(wishlistproductsAdapter);

     }
```

In these arraylist am getting values.how can i set the value on adapter file and UI.

This is my adapter file code:

```
     public class WishListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

         WishListAdapter mListViewAdapter;
          private Activity mActivity;
         private ArrayList<String> mwishlistProducts;
        public ImageLoader mImageLoader; 
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public WishListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> products) {
        mActivity = activity;
           this.mwishlistProducts=products;
          inflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

          class ViewHolder{
            private ImageView productImageView;

             private TextView productTitleView;       
                private TextView productPriceView;  
        private TextView productDescView;   

               public ViewHolder(ImageView productImageView, TextView productTitleView,TextView   productPriceView,TextView productDescView) {
                      super();
        this.productImageView = productImageView;

        this.productTitleView = productTitleView;       
        this.productPriceView = productPriceView;       
        this.productDescView = productDescView;     

    }
} // ViewHolder-class

public int getCount() {
    return mwishlistProducts.size();

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    final String wishlistproductList = mwishlistProducts.get(position);

    if( convertView == null )
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_product, null);  
        ImageView productImage=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);

        TextView productTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.producttitle);
        TextView productPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productprice);
        TextView productDesc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productdescription);

        holder = new ViewHolder(productImage,productTitle,productPrice,productDesc);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                }
    });

    holder.productTitleView.setText();
    holder.productPriceView.setText();
    holder.productDescView.setText();
    mImageLoader=new ImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.DisplayImage();
    return convertView;
}
}
```

In these holder file what i have to set ????

How can i set that arraylist value here.please help me yaar..

**EDIT:**

More products  is displaying on one listview.
Now i have to click one list item means its go to detail description page.here i have to click button means that product detail value is adding and have to display on AddedListProducts Page.

now i ll go to back and click another product means click button means that product detail also added and have to display on AddedListProducts page with that old added products...

i have to add products from that listview and go to next page and clicking button means have to  display that all added products on AddedListProducts page.how can i do ???

Above code ly displaying last added product ly.I want to display all added products on that list.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of *have to*.  Is this a homework problem you're asking for a solution for?

Comment: There is no making sense what you asking?

Comment: Unable to comprehend what exactly you _have to_ do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting value from intent:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

valueaddlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valueaddlist);
        valueaddlist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){
arrayList.add(product_id);
arrayList.add(product_title);
arrayList.add(product_image);
arrayList.add(product_price);
arrayList.add(product_desc);

   } 

valuedisplaylist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valuedisplaylist);
        valuedisplaylist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddedListProducts.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayList", (ArrayList<String>) arrayList);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
```

May be this will help you.

In your second activity get the arraylist like :

```
 ArrayList<String> ar1=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("arrayList"); ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
         new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ar1);
         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Then have a look at this question to display arraylist: [Populating a ListView using an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist)

Comment: yes i get your point..i have added the value on that arraylist.but how can i display on that AddedListProducts.

Comment: @user2218667 Do you have any array list adapter in your AddedListProducts class file?

Comment: please see my adapter file and how can i set the value on that UI...

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(5);
```