# For each key, show value - Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, listview

Im making an app for a site, and i need some help making an for statement. I parse the JSON from the API (Server) and catch it, this is working, however i want it to show in a ListView, i've made my adapter and all that, which is working. Now when i launch the app only one line in the listview shows. So i have no idea on how to get all the values into the listview.

My Activity:

```
public class FilesActivity extends SherlockActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dblist);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Files");

        String response = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://api.bayfiles.net/v1/account/files?session=<SessionId>");

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

               postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
               postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
               response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);
               JSONObject request = new JSONObject(response);
               for (Iterator<?> keyIterator = request.keys(); keyIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                   String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
                   JSONObject object = request.optJSONObject(key);

                   ArrayList<fileObject> objectList = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
                   //ArrayList<fileObject> results = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
                   if (object != null) {
                       fileObject obj = new fileObject();


                       obj.setFileId(key);
                       obj.setFileName(object.getString("filename"));
                       obj.setSize(object.getString("size"));
                       obj.setInfoToken(object.getString("infoToken"));
                       obj.setDeleteToken(object.getString("deleteToken"));
                       obj.setSha1(object.getString("sha1"));
                       objectList.add(obj);

                       Log.d("log_tag", object.getString("filename"));


                   }

                   final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listobjects);
                   lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, objectList));

                   lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                     Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                     fileObject fullObject = (fileObject)o;
                     Toast.makeText(FilesActivity.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + fullObject.getFileName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  
                   });

               }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {      
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

And the adapter and fileObject are just standard, how can i make my listview show all the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [Populating a ListView using an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist)

You're re-creating the arraylist every cycle through the loop. It's only ever going to have one item in it. Just create the ArrayList prior to the for-loop, and populate it inside the loop. Then after you've done that add the whole arraylist to the listview. No need to do it every single cycle. Should look like:

```
           ArrayList<fileObject> objectList = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
           for (Iterator<?> keyIterator = request.keys(); keyIterator.hasNext(); ) {
               String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
               JSONObject object = request.optJSONObject(key);


               //ArrayList<fileObject> results = new ArrayList<fileObject>();
               if (object != null) {
                   fileObject obj = new fileObject();
                   obj.setFileId(key);
                   obj.setFileName(object.getString("filename"));
                   obj.setSize(object.getString("size"));
                   obj.setInfoToken(object.getString("infoToken"));
                   obj.setDeleteToken(object.getString("deleteToken"));
                   obj.setSha1(object.getString("sha1"));
                   objectList.add(obj);
                   Log.d("log_tag", object.getString("filename"));
               }
           }//end the for-loop right here. No need to do that other stuff over and over.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new ArrayList`enter code here` and a new `MyCustomBaseAdapter` in every loop iteration. Move that outside of your loop and it will show all the items.