# Open dialler by list of numbers Android App development

Tags: android

I have a long list of number and i want to open dialer with same number which is clicked if i use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));
startActivity(intent);
```

then I have to write code for every number I want to know how to use single code for every number please help me

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList Phone_Numbers=new ArrayList();

First of all put all the number in the arraylist
then create a listview and set that arraylist to it.

[Populating a ListView using an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist)

then seta setonitemclicklisterner on that list for that have a look at below link

http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

**Explanation for below code**
when you will click on the item on list below listener will be invoked and on that by using **int position** you can get the specific **Phone Number**.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

                // in itemValue you will have the phone number.
                String  itemValue    = Phone_Numbers.get(position);

               //now call the function to open the dialer with that specified number

             open_Phone_Dialer(itemValue);
              }

         }); 

 public void open_Phone_Dialer(String phone_Number) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_Number));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanx Moubeen for your help I give it a try :)

Comment: @axboy Np. Give it a try and if you face issues then feel free to ask.