# Displaying multiple columns and populating correct data using listview

Tags: android

I have string of value that I have stored in my arraylist.Now i want that data to be displayed in form of rows and column and each row must be clickable.so having this search on the net I came to know that using list view will be the best solution but how can i use listview to display multiple columns and how can I populate the value from my array list into differnt column of Listview appropriately?
Need some suggetions people thank you.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-arraylist

Comment: ya thanks for the reply but that example helps in the case of single column i need to have multiple columns..