# How to view the elements of an ArrayList (that contains objects of a custom Customer class that I created) on a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have this ArrayList with 90+ elements in it that is created based on the data I get from a JSON file. I parsed all the neccessary info and created the list successfully.

```
 ArrayList<ExistingCustomer> customers;
```

I need to view the companyName (a string) member field of all the elements of the array on a ListView, and start a new Activity when the user taps on one of them.

I know how to use the adapter when I have a String array but I don't know what to do with an ArrayList. Can you help me out or push me in the right direction?

Edit: No this question has not been asked yet, and it it has, I couldn'T find it. The question you linked me to does not answer my question as it is an example of how to view the elements of a ArrayList structure, not ArrayList.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-an-arraylist

Comment: this does not answer my question.

Comment: What is the problem ? is it : start a new Activity when the user taps on one of them ? or you can't populate the ListView ?