# Fragment- create list view with image ,texts and 3 dots

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-view, android-relativelayout

when user click on **FULL-TIME** button ,I want to open fragment which should display list-view that include **image**, **texts**, and **3 dots** on the right end of each view find image below. how would do this?
  . [image]

this is my code .
**home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_2nd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_full_time"
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/full_time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_part_time"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_full_time"
            android:text="@string/part_time" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_2nd">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Do i need to create separate xml for each view or can i do that programmatically ? please suggest?

Comment: You need to populate the ListView with data programmatically, there are many ways to do that. Maybe start with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070830/populating-a-listview-using-an-arraylist

Comment: You need to create an xml describing single listview item. Then you need to create an Adapter class / or you can use ArrayAdapter initializing using the xml file you create. Then set that adapter to listview.

Comment: Yeah so check this out http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php. Each ListView item/section will need a layout... The layout will have what looks like an image, textviews, and button.

Comment: @Danger hit the nail on the head though. You need the adapter to pass your data into the individual list rows (which have a layout), then apply it to the ListView itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use android RecyclerView with custom item view holder then you can create a custom UI like your list item and add it to your RecyclerView 
See this example

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

for three dots 
create LinewLayout with three Views in vertical order and give them background as custom rounded drwable as :

rounded_view.xml file in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:height="@dimen/dp_10" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

in in your main view Item xml file add this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_view"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_view"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_view"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: seems like lengthy way of coding .I'm able to do this using ListView but unable to add **3 dotes line** and **apply** button on each view see screenshot above.